# steps involved in matrix algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $E$ is a column vector, $\Sigma$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix, Let :
$$
A = E^T \Sigma^{-1}E \quad~~~~~~ B = E^T \Sigma^{-1}1 ~~~~~\quad  C= 1^T \Sigma^{-1}1 \quad 
$$
Then let:
$$
w = \Sigma^{-1} \frac{E (C\mu -B)+1(A-B\mu)}{AC-B^2}
$$
and then I'm really confused how to then get:
$$
w^T \Sigma w = \frac{C\mu^2-2B\mu + A}{AC-B^2}
$$
$\mu$ is a scalar, $1$ is a column vector of ones.
I'm really confused about the algebra involved in getting the last expression, mainly how to treat the transpose of $w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A,B,C$ are all scalars (in fact they are just a fancy dot product from what i can see. Note the same applies to $\vec{w}^T{\Sigma}\vec{w}$ )

$$\vec{w}^T = \frac{(C\mu-B)\vec{E}^T + (A-B\mu)\vec{1}^T}{AC - B^2}\Sigma^{-1}$$

It will be fun to show the last expression, I imagine a beautiful symphony in cancellations. I havent tried evaluating it, I'm curious to know what happens. Will try at some point.